# Managing libraries and dependencies for cross-compiling C/C++

Tags: c++, automation, cross-platform, dependencies

Do any specific tools exist for managing libraries and dependencies for cross-compiling C/C++ projects?

For example, when compiling for a desktop Linux target, one can easily manage libraries and dependencies via `apt-get`, `yum`, `pacman`, `emerge`, etc, depending on the Linux distribution.

But when cross-compiling (say to an ARM target or even to `mingw64`, with 3rd-party libraries like `ICU`, `Boost`, `Qt`, `SQLite`, etc, which have a dependency graph between each other), are there any standard tools to do a similar job?

Currently, I use home-brewed build scripts driven by custom `Makefile`s along with `stow` which I run via inside a `Virtualbox` VM driven by `Vagrant` for setup. While this works and isn't as terrible as compiling lots of things by hand, I have a hard time believing that is really state-of-the-art, yet I've had no luck finding anything even discussing anything like this online.

Comment: I'm not sure you can easily manage the libraries and dependencies you need _for_cross_compiling_ with apt-get, yum etc. Even if it's, say, compiling for a Fedora target on a Debian-based development box.

Answer (score 1):

Try using Cmake it might be useful for you

https://cmake.org/

it manages the build process of Makefiles [that presently you write by hand] on different platforms ... you can simulate the

> CMAKELIST.txt

script for using different tools on different platforms if some are not available on that platform